# SQL Server, add field and view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, sql-server-2012, alter-table

**- Create a table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_tes_test](
[tes_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[tes_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[tes_date] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tb_tit_titti] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [tes_id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**- Add records to table**

```
tes_id  tes_name tes_date
1 tiz   2019-11-28 00:00:00.000
2 cla   2019-10-28 00:00:00.000
3 mar   2019-09-28 00:00:00.000
```

**- Create a view for the table**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_test]
AS
SELECT dbo.tb_tes_test.*
FROM dbo.tb_tes_test
```

**- Add new field to the table between two existent fields**
**- Insert values for the field**

```
tes_id  tes_name    tes_candy   tes_date 1  
1    tiz    com1    2019-11-28 00:00:00.000
2    cla    com2    2019-10-28 00:00:00.000 
3   mar com3    2019-09-28 00:00:00.000
```

**- Run the view with a select * from vw_test**

The result is:

```
tes_id  tes_name    tes_date
1   tiz com1
2   cla com2
3   mar com3
```

**I know that I have to run the alter view to update it, but what if I forget to do it?

Is there an option that update the view automatically?**

Comment: What do you mean by update the view automatically ?

Comment: Not only is there no way to automatically update the view, but best practice is to specify each column name in the view i.e. don't use `*` because that can lead to unpredictable behaviour. Further its recommended to use [SCHEMABINDING](https://www.google.com/search?q=scheme+binding+sql+server&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ697NZ697&oq=scheme+binding+sql+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l3.3615j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to ensure you can't modify the view while it has dependencies. So all in all you should be thinking about restricting the process, not making it automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the view automatically, when a new column is added to a table. A view is a stored query, that accesses one or more tables or views.

As views are often used for security purposes, when you don't want the user to have access to all columns on a table (for example hiding employee salaries, etc). Having views that automatically add new columns would be a bad idea. I'm afraid that if you want to add the column in to the view, then you would need to make the conscious decision to do this.

If you add the SCHEMABINDING construct in your view definition then, when you try to add the new column to the table, it will prevent you due to the binding to the table from the view. This will act as a reminder for you to update the view, at the same time.

Comment: Ok, i know that you should not use * on a view.
The worst thing is that the results are 'scrolled', so the view returns values of column x to column y.
It's very dangerous. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: That's a fair point. If this answers your question, can you please mark it as such? Thank you.